# Gridster angularjs get serialized data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gridster

In angular version of gridster how to get serialized data. Basically i need to get modified position and size of each gridster item. Is there any provision to achieve it? In jquery version of gridster, it provides option of serialize.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I think is to create a function for your button on `ng-click`:

```
//Used to save the dashboard to BOTH local storage and PENN database
//Local storage will attempt to be loaded first. However, if local storage is not there
//then we will load the dashboard from the database
$scope.serialize = function() {

    $scope.dashboardJSON = angular.toJson($scope.standardItems);

    localStorageService.set("DashboardInfo", $scope.dashboardJSON);

    //Send HTTP request 'POST' to saveDashboard function in Rails controller
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'saveDashboard',
        data: {'dashboardInfo': $scope.dashboardJSON },
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            //Let user know that their dashboard was saved with this success flash
            $scope.successSavingDashboardToDBAlert();
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config)
        {
            //Let the user know the dashboard could not be saved with this error flash
            $scope.errorSavingDashboardToDBAlert();
        }); 

};
```

`$scope.dashboardJSON` then will look like this:

```
[
  {
    "name":           "Speedometer",
    "sizeX":          2,
    "sizeY":          3,
    "content":        "<speeometer></speedometer>",
    "widgetSettings": {"id":2},
    "market":         "Medical",
    "duration":       "Monthly",
    "total":          0,
    "showTarget":     true,
    "row":            0,
    "col":            0
  }
]
```